# Should the age of a user profile determine rep?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, reputation, up-votes

When looking at the oldest posts of a site, I tend to find many non-active users with very high rep, just because their questions have been around the longest.

Is it fair that the users who signed up to the site first should have high reputations, even if they are not active or did not put much effort in?

I propose that upvotes on questions/answers give one less reputation point for every year that the question/answer is old, until a minimum of one point for every upvote is reached.

This would mean that a good answer would receive the usual amount of reputation benefits for one year, slightly less in year two, and as time goes on, eventually reaching one point for every upvote at the start of year 10. People do not really look at old questions as much anyway.

Comment: Reputation tends to reflect **activity** on the site. A new user can certainly gain reputation very quickly. The people who have lots of reputation *earned* it.

Comment: [Here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/5/151595) and [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/107/151595) are good examples of the problem I'm thinking of. These users haven't put in as much work as later users on M.SE.

Comment: To me it would be much more interesting if the age of the *vote* was considered.  So a ten-year-old upvote on an answer would only be worth 1 point, having declined in value by one point every year.  But a new upvote on a ten-year-old answer would still be worth 10 points.  This would cause the reputation of long-time users to "age away," which I think is what you are going for.  Still not something I'd support, but more interesting.

Comment: @Nathaniel good idea.

Comment: @ahorn 1K, 4K rep aren't *very high reputation* scores, got better examples?

Comment: I'm not proposing this out of spite. To the contrary, I recently hit the daily limit from a single question on a young site (English Language Usage), which surprised me. I didn't feel like I earned it, and I may well get more from that question in the future.

Comment: @Mat's Mug no. The issue obviously isn't a HUGE problem.

Comment: This is why I am a big proponent of **per-post rep cap** (instead of *per day*). Better solution than this.

Answer (score 11):

> People do not really look at old questions as much anyway.

So what is the point in taking away reputation from an upvote then? If a question gets one view a year and that single view yields an upvote, what is the purpose of awarding less reputation? Was the post less useful than it was before? No. So why should it not be awarded exactly that as it was a year before, when it was useful too?

This proposal doesn't fix any issue.

Comment: Not to mention, that the people that *do their homework* and actually *search before asking*, **do** end up finding *and [hopefully] upvoting* old questions and answers.

Answer (score 10):

Counterpoints.

1. Users who were with a site from the beginning worked to define it, and bring it into shape through their contributions. This work should not be simply devalued.
2. The point of (most) Stack Exchange sites is to build a repository of awesome answers to useful questions. For many sites, an awesome answer from five years ago is probably still an awesome answer, and should be rewarded as such. The usefulness of a question also doesn't depend on how fresh it is. In fact, it's these long-lasting pearls that we should be encouraging.
3. This proposal would encourage users to answer duplicate questions (with duplicate answers) instead of properly closing duplicate questions as such.

That "[p]eople do not really look at old questions as much anyway" is actually more of a problem than a justification for changing the reputation reward of upvoted older posts.